# Parrot Security OS или Kali Linux

Tags: linux, parrot

Здрайствуйте, как считаете, какой дистрибутив лучше поставить как основной на ноутбук, Parrot Secutity OS или Kali Linux?

Comment: Лучше Windows .

Comment: Поставь blackarch

Comment: Советую Kali, заодно поиграетесь с различными интересными утилитами, которых нет в других дистрибутивах

Comment: Matther Benjamin, как отдельный дистрибутив, или просто добавить его репозиторий? я знаю, что можно добавить просто к репозиторию manjaro

Comment: почему все вдруг ставят Kali или подобные дистрибутивы? все вдруг решили стать безопасниками?

Answer (score 0):

Kali стабильнее будет. Mate, с которым поставляется Parrot, у меня работает не очень